# Using devise_security_extension with Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

```
Rails 3.2
```

I am working on Rails application, using Devise for User management. The new requirement, is to add some rules, to

- Insure that passwords are at between 8 and 70 chars long, and have at least one lower case character, one upper case character, one numeral and one special character.
- Old passwords are archived, up to 6
- Cannot use a password that's in the archive
- passwords expire after 3 months
- Accounts that have not been used in more than 3 months are expired
- Sessions expire after 15 minutes of inactivity

I added the following to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'devise_security_extension', '0.10.0'
```

and to my config/initializers/devise.rb, I added the following:

```
config.expire_password_after = 3.months
config.password_regex= /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,70}$/
config.password_archiving_count = 6
config.deny_old_passwords = true
config.expire_after = 3.months
config.timeout_in = 15.minutes
config.expire_auth_token_on_timeout = true
```

I modified my models/user.rb, as follows:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :invitable,
     :confirmable, :password_expirable, :secure_validatable, :password_archivable,
     :session_limitable, :expirable
```

I then did the following:

```
bundle install
rails generate devise_security_extension:install
```

Based on advice from StackOverflow, I also did the following:

```
rails g migration AddPasswordChangedAtToUser password_changed_at:datetime:index
```

Which produced the following migration:

```
class AddPasswordChangedAtToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :password_changed_at, :datetime
    add_index :users, :password_changed_at
  end
end
```

Then, I did the following:

```
rails g migration CreateOldPasswordsTable
```

Which created a migration, that I edited as follows:

```
class CreateOldPasswordsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration  
  create_table :old_passwords do |t|
    t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false
    t.string :password_archivable_type, :null => false
    t.integer :password_archivable_id, :null => false
    t.datetime :created_at
  end
  add_index :old_passwords, [:password_archivable_type, :password_archivable_id], :name => :index_password_archivable
end
```

I ran the migrations, and made sure the table users was modified, and the table old_passwords was created

When I ran the app, I got the login screen, and when I tried to login, using my existing credentials, I got the following (from the log file):

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 63.251.170.1 at 2018-10-24 00:08:34 +0000
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Mi9uscJh/b6qusoV3kclz7FXWj952AnYV9mNwURG8tQ=", "user"=>{"email"=>"xxxxx@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.4ms)[0m  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'xxxxx@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 81.7ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `expired_at' for #<User:0x0000000a91b360>):
  app/middleware/catch_json_parse_errors.rb:8:in `call'
```

Any ideas?

## What worked:

I was missing the following modifications to the users table:

```
add_column :users, :password_changed_at, :datetime
add_index :users, :password_changed_at
add_column :users, :unique_session_id, :string, :limit => 20
add_column :users, :last_activity_at, :datetime
add_index :users, :last_activity_at
add_column :users, :expired_at, :datetime
add_index :users, :expired_at
```

Comment: I think this gem is not really maintained which I think is an issue. Though try to generate a migration and add this field. This is probably necessary in order to meet requirements of new features. Just make it a timestamp and check if it works. Though what is strange is that passwords are encrypted with Bcrypt and salted. Basically two different  encrypted versions of a password can originate from the exact same string. So you can't prevent reuse of a same password over time. (Afaik.. but I may be wrong)

Comment: (you can easily check my assumption about passwords by creating two dummy user accounts with Devise with same password. The encrypted password will be different for the two accounts)

Comment: @Maxence I am not really sure what you're saying here. I created a migration, per instruction. What migration do you want me to add?

Comment: Well I mean you could try adding this field to the User model, like you did when you added field `password_changed_at` (the first migration you mentioned). It seems other users have done it too https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension/issues/193

Comment: is `expired_at` a `User` field? did you create the field with  a migration? `self.expired_at` is called in a couple of places https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension/blob/master/lib/devise_security_extension/models/expirable.rb#L29 and I believe it is part of your `3.months` expire strategy.